# Security question regarding document in siteassets of a site collection being accessed in subsites

Tags: site-collection, sharepoint-server

I created a site collection that has about 50 subsites under it.  Each subsite has individual security.  I put a link to a document in the main collection's site assets so that I would only have to change the document once and it would be changed everywhere.  However, now the users can't see the document from the sub sites.

I am very new to sharepoint so I am not sure exactly what to do.  The visitor's group in the collection is blank...should I add "Everyone" to that group?  Seems to me a little dangerous so I figured I would ask here first.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you ought to grant Everyone read access to the root site (or the site assets container in the root site).

If your subsites are not inheriting permissions from the root (i.e. inheritance is broken) then you need not worry about all users gaining access to all subsites.

I suggest you investigate your permissions structure and test with a test user account before you go for the jugular and grant read to all users.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have added "Everyone" to the permissions of the Site Assets library only and set it not to inherit the permissions.  The problem with "test" is that where I am, there isn't a real test environment so it's basically fly by the seat of my pants...and learn as I go too.  But it isn't as if there are NSA secrets in there or anything so I think it will be OK. ;)   Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help. One note about testing: if you don't have access to a full-blown test environment, you can always just create a test user account (in production), give it the permissions you desire, then log on as the test user and check to ensure they have the proper, expected access.